# How get then color number of the text and the color background with mvinch

Tags: c, gcc, ncurses

Thank you very much for the previous answer, but i have another question.

How i can get the color text and the color bacground of the character,if i don't know what is the color used.
I your example, you know what is the color; and then you can compare; but if you don't know what is the color; how i can get the color Than you.

This is the code that you send me.

```
init_pair(1, COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_BLACK);
init_pair(2, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLACK);
init_pair(3, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLACK);

attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
mvprintw(1, 1, "Sky");

attron(COLOR_PAIR(2));
mvprintw(2, 1, "Grass");


const int color_one = mvinch(1, 1) & A_COLOR;
const int color_two = mvinch(2, 1) & A_COLOR;

attron(COLOR_PAIR(3));

if ( color_one == COLOR_PAIR(1) ) {
    mvprintw(4, 1, "Sky is blue");
}
else if ( color_one == COLOR_PAIR(2) ) {
    mvprintw(4, 1, "Sky is green");
}
else if ( color_one == COLOR_PAIR(3) ) {
    mvprintw(4, 1, "Sky is white");
}

if ( color_two == COLOR_PAIR(1) ) {
    mvprintw(5, 1, "Grass is blue");
}
else if ( color_two == COLOR_PAIR(2) ) {
    mvprintw(5, 1, "Grass is green");
}
else if ( color_two == COLOR_PAIR(3) ) {
    mvprintw(5, 1, "Grass is white");
}

refresh();
getch();
endwin();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the COLOR_PAIR number use:

```
int color_pair = PAIR_NUMBER(mvinch(1,1));
```

Which will return the color pair (1 in this case)

Then pass this number to:

```
int foreground , background;
pair_content(color_pair, &foreground, &background);
```

To get the colors.

If you want the rgb for a color use:

```
int r, g, b;
color_content(foreground, &r, &g, &b);
```